# How to to migrate the code I have from Manifest 2 to 3

Tags: javascript, json, manifest, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How to to migrate the code I have from Manifest 2 to 3. I changed the 2 to a 3. Thanks!

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Algebra-Geometry",
  "description": "Learn Algebra and Geometry!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["main.js", "popup.js"]
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).

Comment: 1) `browser_action` to `action`, 2) `<all_urls>` into `host_permissions`.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: First, I suggest you go through the official [migration checklist](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/) to switch from Manifest2 to Manifest3. It's straightforward to understand from their official website.

If you still need assistance, here's the long answer for that:

While doing the conversion from manifest 2 to 3, it is mentioned in the migration guide that:

> In Manifest V3, you'll need to specify [host permissions and optional
> host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#:%7E:text=%22host_permissions%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%22http%3A//www.blogger.com/%22%2C%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22optional_host_permissions%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%22*%3A//*/*%22%2C%0A%20%20%5D:%7E:text=%22host_permissions%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%22http%3A//www.blogger.com/%22%2C%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22optional_host_permissions%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%22*%3A//*/*%22%2C%0A%20%20%5D) separately from other permissions.

Also, manifest 3 will not be supported by the chrome version below 93.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Algebra-Geometry",
  "description": "Learn Algebra and Geometry!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "93",
  "action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["main.js", "popup.js"]
      }
  ]
}
```

In addition, with Manifest V3, chrome planned to drop support for  and start asking for permissions at runtime, using [activeTab][3] host permission by default. So I'm not quite sure about the  thing.

> ```
> {
>   ...
>   "permissions": [
>     "tabs",
>     "bookmarks"
>   ],
>   "optional_permissions": [
>     "unlimitedStorage"
>   ],
>   "host_permissions": [
>     "http://www.blogger.com/",
>   ],
>   "optional_host_permissions": [
>     "*://*/*",
>   ]
>   ...
> }
> ```